# How to solve this error with storing data into database when user is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to resolve this kind of problem:

1. When guest go to support.php page and write his name, phone, email, website and message information, message successfully send to database.
2. Problem is on this part. When user log in into his account on website, and visit same page support.php and try to send message, if user logged in that page recognize personal information (name, email, phone) and user need to enter just website and message info on submit i get error that field name, email and phone didn't entered or null.

This is code:

Support.php

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="themeQuote.php" role="form">
    <div class="messages"></div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="form_name" class="mbr-white text-center">Name <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Please enter your name *" required="required" data-error="Valid name is required." value="<?php echo $userData['first_name']; ?>">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_phone" class="mbr-white text-center">Phone number <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                    <input id="form_phone" type="text" name="text" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Please enter your phone number *" required="required" data-error="Valid phone number is required." value="<?php echo $userData['phone']; ?>">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_email" class="mbr-white text-center">Email <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" readonly placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required." value="<?php echo $userData['email']; ?>">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_website" class="mbr-white text-center">Website url <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                    <input id="form_website" type="text" name="website" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your website url *" required="required" data-error="Valid website url is required.">
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="form_message" class="mbr-white text-center">Describe the customization required <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block sgn" value="Request a quote">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

And themeQuote.php code is:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "support";

try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username,
    $password);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// prepare sql and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO quote_theme (name, phone, 
email, website, message) 
VALUES (:name, :phone, :email, :website, :message)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':phone', $phone);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':website', $website);
$stmt->bindParam(':message', $message);

// insert a row
$name = $_POST["name"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$website = $_POST["website"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$stmt->execute();


header('Location: theme-customization-success');
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
?>
```

This is code when user is logged in, u can see that because i added on fields name, phone, email php code `<?php echo $userData['email']; ?>`. How php code can get that value and store into database.

I apologize for bad English. Im sure u figure what i want and where is problem.
Thanks all

Comment: What exactly are you tying to do ?

Comment: Problem is fixed. On field phone name was text that is error, name must be phone because of php code and base. Thanks peopel @ths

Answer (score -1):

Problem is on Phone field, i find it.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="form_website" class="mbr-white text-center">Website url <span class="text-red">*</span></label>
    <input id="form_website" type="text" name="website" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your website url *" required="required" data-error="Valid website url is required.">
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks, code is working!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `phone` field ??